# RegEx - Select string after user defined text and stop at first line feed

Tags: regex, power-automate

Using Power Automate Desktop to get something from a WebPage, but I need some help please.

Sample data:

```
Car: New
Model: ABCD XPTO
BHP: 90
```

I'm trying to get the text after the "Car: ", "Model: " or "BHP: " but to stop before the line break or before the next line that has **:**

I've tried:

```
(?<=Model: ).+
(?<=Model: )(.*?)(?=[\n\r])
```

But, the 1st returns the model and everything after. The 2nd returns an empty string. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Unless you use the `s` flag, `.` will not match a newline, so you don't need to do anything to stop at the end of the line.

Comment: But if Power Automate is different, the second version should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Barmar. Pretty new to RegEx, how can I insert the /s flag, and where, in the whole regex expression?

Comment: Try `(?<=Model: )[^\r\n]+`

Comment: The fourth bird, that got it :)
Could you help me with another?
I have:
Model
Arteon

How can I search for "Model", get the next line feed text and stop there?
Tried (?<=Model\r|Model\n|Model\r\n)[^\r\n]+
and always return:
Model
Arteon

Comment: You don't want to insert the `s` flag, that would make `.*` match across newlines, which is what you don't want.

Comment: If you want The fourth bird to be notified, put `@` before their name. You can start typing their name, then press TAB for completion.

Comment: @The fourth bird it seems after all it doesn't work quite well. In Extraction Preview it shows okay, but when saving to Excel it shows the model and every other word until the end of the text block. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following

```
(?<=Car: ).*?(?=\n|$)
```

This would capture right after "Car: " until either a newline character or the end of the string is reached.

For the Model:

```
(?<=Model: ).*?(?=\n|$)
```

For BHP:

```
(?<=BHP: ).*?(?=\n|$)
```

If you want to capture everything in one RegEx, I would suggest the following:

```
(?<=(Model|Car|BHP): ).*?(?=\n|$)
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Also, might I suggest using a RegEx site where you can test your expressions; I use the following one: https://regexlearn.com/playground